# Bootstrap & scrollr fullscreen background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and have placed a number of fullscreen background images that were working perfectly. Tonight I added Scrollr to the site and now the background images are all blown up and I can't figure out why?

html

```
<header id="top" class="header">
    <div class="container text-vertical-center">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="center-block">
            <div class="padded" style="border: 1px solid white">
        <h1 class="title text-uppercase"><font color="#FFFFFF">Language</font></h1>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="scroll">
        <i class="icon-double-angle-down icon-large"></i>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

css

```
.header {
display: table;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url(../img/test.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```

I have also added height and width to the html and body tags at the top of my css.

```
html,
body 
#skrollr-body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't to add comment. Can you describe how it looks now? At first look it seems all is well. Maybe try ro change your `position` for `absolute` or `fixed`

Comment: I tried changing the position to absolute and fixed and the whole section disappears? It seems that something in the Scrollr plugin is overriding height:100% and the images are displaying at their full size...?

Comment: try to remove display and scroll in no-repeat center center scroll;

Comment: In the end this css worked for me:
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../img/10Church3/small_IMG_9479.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;